# graph points distance problem.

Tags: graph-theory

there are $n \geq 3$ points in plane where each two points have distance at least $1$.
I know there are at most $ 3n - 6 $ pairs with the distance exactly $1$.

I want to prove this fact.

Comment: Have you tried proving this by induction in $n$?

Comment: If I'm understanding the statement correctly, I found a counterexample for $n=7$.

Comment: could you please post how to prove with insuction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that the number of pairs at distance $\leq1$ is at most $3n-6$ we have to prove that the number of such ordered pairs is at most $6n-12$. That is, calling our set $S$ and $\phi(P)$ the number of points of $S$ at distance 1 from $P$, we have to show that $\sum_{P\in S}\phi(P)\leq 6n-12$.

Now consider $A$, the convex closure of the set $S$. It is a convex poligon, and its vertices are points of $S$, so it has a finite number $n$ of vertices. Call them $P_1,\dots,P_n$, and call $\alpha_n$ the interior angle of the poligon at $P_n$ (for example in the equilateral triangle, $\alpha_n=\frac{\pi}{3}$).

Given some $P_n$, the points at distance $1$ of $P_n$ will have to be in a circumference arc at distance $1$ of $P_n$ and of angle $\alpha_n$. As $\alpha_n<\pi$, there can´t be more than 3 points at distance 1 of $P_n$. That means the $P_n$ have at most 3 adjacent vertices. Thus, if there are 4 or more $P_n$, we have ended because, using that $\phi(P)\leq6$ for all $P$, we have that $\sum_{P\in S}\phi(P)$ will be $\leq6n-12$.

If there are only 3 vertices of $A$, $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$, then $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=\pi$. If the three angles are $\frac{\pi}{3}$, then $P_1,P_2$ and $P_3$ have at most 2 adjacent points each, and $\sum_{P\in S}\phi(P)\leq 6n-12$. If not, there must be one point with $\alpha_i<\frac{\pi}{3}$ (which can only have one adjacent point), and the other two points can´t have both $\alpha_i\geq\frac{2\pi}{3}$, so they can´t have both more than 2 adjacent points each. So they can´t have more than 5 adjacent points between the two of them. Using this, we reach in this case too the conclusion that $\sum_{P\in S}\phi(P)\leq 6n-12$.

Answer (score 1):

(Answer to the unedited question which asked to prove there are at most 2n-6 pairs with distance 1)
The hexagon shown in the figure has side 2. Consider a similar hexagon of side $n$.

[image]

Then it´s easy to show it will have $3n^2+3n+1$ points. Moreover, each point not in the edge ($3n(n-1)+1$ points) will have 6 points at distance 1. The non vertex points of the edges ($6(n-1)$ points) will have 4 adjacent points, and the vertices ($6$ points) will have 3 adjacent points. Taking into account that we´ve counted each pair 2 times, we have a total of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(6(3n(n-1)+1)+4(6(n-1))+6\cdot3)=9n^2+3n$ pairs of points at distance one. For $n\geq2$, that is bigger than $2\cdot(3n^2+3n+1)-6$, so your conjecture is false.

A bound for the number of pairs is: if you have $k$ points at distance $\geq1$, then there can´t be more than $3k$ pairs of distance $1$. This is obvious since each point corresponds to at most other six points at distance 1, that is, there are at most $6k$ ordered pairs of points at distance 1, and as you count the pairs 2 times, there are at most $3k$ pairs of points at distance 1. This bound can probably be lowered a bit with a more refined argument looking at the points "in the edge of the set".

Comment: you are right. i think the statement should be 3n-6. so i edited his question.

Comment: exactly ! thanks

Comment: Ok, I posted the new answer separately because it wasn´t too related to the previous one. I think there should be a bound of the type $3n-k\sqrt{n}$, where $k>0$, but that would probably require a more complex argument.